# Finite sum of csc via sum of cot

Tags: calculus, analysis, summation

Would anyone give a clue how to prove the following identity:

$\sum_{k =1}^{n-1} \csc\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right) = -\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(2k+1)\cot\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2n}\right)$.

I tried various methods with no success.

This formula is given as an excercise in H. Chen "Excursions in classical analysis" in Chapter 7.

Comment: Would you be fine with proof by induction?

Comment: Yes, sure. Thanks. Would be glad to see it.

Comment: Okay. Let me try it out.

Comment: Would you mind giving some examples of what you've tried, even without success?

Comment: I tried induction (of course), power series for $\cot$ and $\csc$, plus various trigonometric identities, for example, $\csc(x)=\cot(x/2) - \cot(x)$, including finite sums I could find in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities and in Wolfram https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Cot/introductions/Cot/ShowAll.html

Comment: and also, tried to find general function identity as if you notice derivative of $\log(\sin(2k+1)x)$ gives $(2k+1)\cot((2k+1)x)$.

Comment: May you please put your work in the post? You have some interesting ideas.

Comment: this question should not have been closed, it is clear what is asked for and there is a reference too. the closing of this question is typical of stackexchange misuse and does not allow further answers to be contributed.

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(2k+1)\cot\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2n}\right)$$ as
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}k\cot\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}2k\cot\left(\frac{2k\pi}{2n}\right).$$ Then use $\cot\left(\dfrac{(2n-s)\pi}{2n}\right)=-\cot\left(\dfrac{s\pi}{2n}\right)$ and $\cot\left(\dfrac{n\pi}{2n}\right)=0$ to rewrite the first sum, giving $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(k-(2n-k))\cot\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}2k\cot\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)=-2n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\cot\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}2k\csc\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right),$$ from the identity $\csc x = \cot \frac{1}{2}x - \cot x$.

Also, $$n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\csc\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right) = n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\cot\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right) -n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\cot\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)$$ and the second of these sums is zero, using $\cot\left(\dfrac{(n-k)\pi}{n}\right)=-\cot\left(\dfrac{k\pi}{n}\right)$, so  $$n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\csc\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(2k+1)\cot\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2n}\right) = -n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\cot\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right) +\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}2k\csc\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right).$$ Finally, because $\csc\left(\dfrac{k\pi}{n}\right) =\csc\left(\dfrac{(n-k)\pi}{n}\right)$,$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k\csc\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(n-k)\csc\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right),$$ so $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}2k\csc\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}n\csc\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}n\cot\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}n\cot\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)$$ and $$n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\csc\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(2k+1)\cot\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2n}\right) = -n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\cot\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)=0.$$

Comment: thank you very much! beautiful